# Exception When I Cast cmbx into database entity

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

Here is the thing, its my first time writing, hope you don't judge too much! :)

I will also be thorough so You can fully understand.

I have created a database with a few tables, one of them is `Genre`.
I use the ADO.NET entity data model for the WPF connection with the given database. I have created a method in GenreDal for deleting a selected Genre.
Made a combobox with Genres(names) in it and a button delete.
In the clickEvent i typed

```
{
   Genre g = (Genre)comboboxGenre.SelectedItem; 
   GenreDal d = new GenreDal(); 
   d.RemoveGenre(g); 
}
```

after this i run and test the app, but an exception pops up everytime. saying that it

> cannot convert "System.String" to "MusicStoreApp"

I don't get it, hope You people can help out!
If you need more info, just ask.

Comment: tried it, still nothing :/ i've tried all of the "selected" properties, all the same, Unable to convert type System.String into type MusicStore.Genre.

Comment: It seems that the comboboxGenre contains only the name of Genres as a string. So, you can't cast string to Genre. Please show us how do you fill the combobox

Comment: Filling combobox: GenreDal d = new GenreDal(); comboboxZanr.Itemssource = d.ShowGenres().Select(p => p.GenreName);

Comment: How? I don't see anything. Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information

Comment: sorry, still learning the methods of typing here :) i have edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from  comboboxZanr.Itemssource = d.ShowGenres().Select(p => p.GenreName);` you are binding to IEnumerable OF STRINGS  to get it work, you have to bind to list of your model. List

```
comboboxZanr.Itemssource = d.ShowGenres();
```

then you can do

```
 Genre g = (Genre)comboboxGenre.SelectedItem; 
   GenreDal d = new GenreDal(); 
   d.RemoveGenre(g);
```

Comment: if i type just comboboxGenre.Itemssource =  d.ShowGenres(); it just end up giving me System.Data.Entities.Proxie etc. 

   List<Genre> ShowGenres(){using(MusicStoreEntities mr = new MusicStoreEntities()){ return mr.Genre.ToList();}}

this is how i created the method

Comment: In your combobox set DisplayMemberPath="Name"

Answer (score 0):

thank you all i kinda took each of the advice and combined them, and figured it out, with the help of

```
cmbx.DisplayMemberPath = "GenreName";
cmbx.SelectedValuePath = "GenreId";
```

tnx again :)

Answer (score -1):

You say in your post *Made a combobox with Genres(names) in it and a button delete* ... which means your combobox is a collection of `string` and thus `SelectedItem` gets you the currently select genre name which is `string` and which obviously can't be casted back to `Genre` object since it's not a `Genre` type.

Solution:

Either you construct your combobox with `List<Genre>` as the datasource.

Or, get the selected Genre name from the combobox and then get the specific Genre like

```
string genrename = comboboxGenre.SelectedItem;
Genre g = db.Genres.Single(g => g.Name == genrename);
```

** Considering that genre names are Unique else `Single()` will throw exception.

Comment: yes, but i used GenreDal method ShowGenre() and lambda expression to show just the names of the Genres

Comment: I gotta see how it works with List<Genre> because the second solution doesent work